# How to avoid injection of $scope into angular service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Angular extends the 'this' variable of a service function with the scope (viewmodel) of the controller that is using it. Maybe I'm misunderstanding a design-intention here but it makes no sense to me.

[Here's an example on codepen to illustrate the problem](http://codepen.io/goodafternoon/pen/uvyDc?editors=001). When the class function (TestService) gets initiated, `this` is empty, but after a brief timeout, it suddenly contains the `$scope` from the controller.

**How can I avoid the injection of $scope into my Service?**

Optionally, It'd be great if you could explain the reasoning behind this behaviour as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your dependency injection. You have used

`angular.module('app', ['service']).controller('ctrl', ['testService', function($scope, testService){`

Whereas it should be

`angular.module('app', ['service']).controller('ctrl', ['$scope','testService', function($scope, testService){`

So what you thought was scope is actually the service itself `testService`. Scopes can never be injected into service, even if you want to. You can only inject `$rootSscope` into a service.

Another advice that i would want to share, would be to not do DOM referencing in controller, service better to go with directives.

Comment: The dom reference was only for purpose of demonstration. Hehe, a typo! Silly me! For a moment I was convinced I found a bug in angular :D